# Creating a char rectangle in phyton using for loop

Tags: for-loop

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dt6C.png)

```py
def draw_rectangle(height,width,char):  
    for h in range(height):
        for w in range(width): 
            print("char", end="") 
        print()
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is:
You wrote `print("char", end="")`, so your code printed the word "char" instead of the variable `char`.

Here's the corrected code:

```py
def draw_rectangle(height,width,char):  
    for h in range(height):
        for w in range(width): 
            print(char, end="") # don't use '"', if you want to print a variable's value instead of a string
        print()
```

Please, next time give more information about your problem (does it throw error, or just don't do what you want to do, if throws error, what kind of error), so it will be easier to help.